# Azure Logic App + SendGrid Email link formatting

Tags: azure, sendgrid, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is being used to send emails using a SendGrid subscription. There is a unique link sent to each user. I can embed this link variable in the message text using expressions, but when the email is sent it transforms the link to plain text.

There is a "link" button that can be used to manually add a link but it only accepts plain text as the link title and target, it does not appear it can be mapped to any expressions or dynamic content.

I thought I could maybe add a placeholder link through the SendGrid Link insertion, and then find it in the corresponding json template for the app and map it to an expression but something happens when it is saved and it is transformed.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Any update about this post ?

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, it doesn't show same problem in my side. I received the email in outlook and in my opinion, it may be influenced by your email tool. In my side, the link was transformed to plain text only if the email is filtered into Junk Folder.

To solve this problem, you can test it in another email tool. Or you can do it like below screenshot, store the link with `<a>` tag in a variable and then use the variable in email body.

[image]